# Pinterest Integration

Tags: ios, pinterest

My ImageURL is http://aeonit.name/azva/admin/images/product/1136X640/1383892344_Bridal_bangles_crafted_in_rava_and_ghungroo_work.png

and imageUrlForPinImages = path to directory where image is stored

Below is my code :

```
{

    ProductDetails *prodOBJ = [imageArray objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString * imageURL=[imageUrlForPinImages stringByAppendingPathComponent:prodOBJ.pinImage];
    pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:@"1433948" urlSchemeSuffix:@"prod"];
    [pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlForPinImages] description:imageURL];
}
```

When I run I get following error:

```
Invalid Parameters.
Parameter 'image_url'(value http://aeonit.name/azva/admin/images/product/1136X640/1383892344_Bridal_bangles_crafted_in_rava_and_ghungroo_work.png) is not a valid url format.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?